# Asp.net Core MVC application with Azure AD authentication. Unable to unprotect Message.State on browser back button

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application which is integrated with AZURE AD for authentication.
The problem is that when redirecting between the pages it issues a request to a url something similar to :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/e3a291d3-8a20-4c35-8d08-38ffcafa479d/oauth2/authorize?client_id=86cda223-2296-46c3-a...
```

it automatically authenticated and next page loads perfectly fine. but if I press back button then it gets redirected back to this weird login url. And that's when it throws exception.

[image]

Comment: The integrated authentication with AD works with much back and forth interaction between your webserver & the Microsoft auth server, pressing the back button is going to cause issue, it works by design.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds that you can try is to add reply / redirect url to your app in Azure Ad as so, The Reply URL will deliver the authentication response, which will include a token if authentication is successful. Aslo try adding the **PostLogoutRedirectURI** in your appSettings where Azure AD will redirect the user-agent in an OAuth 2.0 request.

[image]

For Adding Reply URL you can navigate to Settings > Reply URLs and set the URL to the page where the user will be directed after logging in.

**REFERENCE:**
[Reply URLs vs PostLogoutRedirectURIs in Azure Active Directory (AAD) | by Marilee Turscak](https://marileeturscak.medium.com/reply-urls-vs-postlogoutredirecturis-in-azure-active-directory-aad-20f57a03267b)

Here is a similar Thread you can refer to [Error code  "Unable to unprotect the message.State" when redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62791068/error-code-500-unable-to-unprotect-the-message-state-when-redirecting-to-clien)

Comment: I tried adding "PostLogoutRedirectURI:"https : //xyz.com/platform/signin-oidc" which is same as the RedirectUrl i already had in the application and in azure portal. Didn't work :/